# Rvest not returning html_nodes whan id of xpath has an accent in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to scrape a table from an html file using Rvest in R. But html_node is not working, I think it is because the id in the xpath is in Spanish and has an accent.

Here is the code:

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url <- "https://www3.ine.gub.uy/boletin/Boletin%20Ingresos%204to%20trimestre%202021.html"
html <- read_html(url)
data <- html_node(html, xpath='//*[@id="ingreso-medio-per-cápita"]/table/tbody')
```

I have been Googling a lot but I cannot find a solution.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is here, but since the string up to the accented character is still unique, you can get it using the xpath function `starts-with`

```r
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url <- "https://www3.ine.gub.uy/boletin/Boletin%20Ingresos%204to%20trimestre%202021.html"
html <- read_html(url)

xpath <- '//div[starts-with(@id,"ingreso-medio-per-c")]/table'
data <- html_table(html_nodes(html, xpath = xpath))[[1]][1:3,]
#> Warning in table_fill(cells, trim = trim): NAs introduced by coercion

data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   ``         `Trimestre 3 2021` `Trimestre 4 2021`
#>   <chr>                   <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1 Total país               25.8               26.6
#> 2 Montevideo               32.5               33.5
#> 3 Interior                 21.5               22.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use,

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url = 'https://www3.ine.gub.uy/boletin/Boletin%20Ingresos%204to%20trimestre%202021.html'

url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table()
```

to get all the tables from webpage.